# Verify SHA-256 sum of a file and exit the script if not as intended

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, sha

I am attempting to make a bash script to auto-install a software I frequently work with, and I've arrived at a small issue. I would like my script to verify the validity of the downloaded file's sha256sum and either respond with a message of success or exit with an error message if it isn't what is expected.

Here's what I've tried so far (It works somewhat but doesn't exit on failure):

```
shasum panel.tar.gz |
awk $1=="acca80528628ad362c5733229203a6c4bb3d648a9c40be318ff9f4f9653d505d"{print"SHA256SUM validated, installation may proceed"}
```

It's a part of an installation script, I'd like for it to verify the shasum and then if it doesn't match the expected `acca80528628ad362c5733229203a6c4bb3d648a9c40be318ff9f4f9653d505d`, it should exit the entire script. The line I gave above keeps the script going as-is without stopping, even if the shasum doesn't match the expected.

Comment: Can you add some more details on what you'd expect to happen in the case of which failure? What do you mean by 'doesn't exit on failure'. Does it run forever, then?

Comment: It's a part of an installation script, I'd like for it to verify the shasum and then if it doesn't match the expected "acca80528628ad362c5733229203a6c4bb3d648a9c40be318ff9f4f9653d505d", it should exit the entire script. The line I gave above keeps the script going as-is without stopping, even if the shasum doesn't match the expected.

Comment: I believe `shasum` calculates the SHA-1 checksum, not the SHA-256 checksum. For SHA-256 you need `shasum  --algorithm 256`.

Comment: Related: [How to take sha256sum of file and compare to check in one line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1312740/how-to-take-sha256sum-of-file-and-compare-to-check-in-one-line)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a process substitution to create the checksum file for `shasum -c` on the fly:

```
checksum=acca80528628ad362c5733229203a6c4bb3d648a9c40be318ff9f4f9653d505d
shasum -c <(echo "$checksum panel.tar.gz")
```

Or pipe the contents to `shasum`, using `-` as the file name:

```
echo "$checksum panel.tar.gz" | shasum -c -
```

Look at the exit status to determine whether to continue.

```
if ! echo "$checksum panel.tar.gz" | shasum -c -; then
    echo "Checksum failed" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

If you don't want to do anything other than exit immediately, you can use

```
echo "$checksum panel.tar.gz" | shasum -c - || exit 1
```

Comment: How would I go about stopping the script automagically if the outputted sha256sum doesn't match with what is expected?

Comment: @david71726 - An example of comparing and stopping the script is [here](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts/blob/master/build-wget-lite.sh#L52).

Comment: Why `sha256sum` does not have an option to simply compare a file hash with a string directly?

Answer (score 0):

Simple use case, sign and verify a file against a given sum, in the view of proving ownership, and content integrity.

---

The author publish a file, and a sha256 *fingerprint* sum.

To get the sum, the author simply does:

```
sha256sum file
```

He gets a sha256 sum and the file name, **separated by two spaces**.

---

The reader, or anyone wanting to verify if the file is **NOT altered**, can do:

```
if [[ $(sha256sum file) = "75efecda52220be1c97ab2b29cd2880a089dff40b0f7967653535cb8b02e8cc2  file" ]];then echo "Signature OK"; fi
```